# Slides are broken when rotating devices on amp-carousel slides on iphone safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-safari, amp-html

I am using the latest version of amp-carousel version 0.2

There are no problems with amp-carousel but one problem. On iphone safari browser, when rotating devices, the slides are broken (from second slide.)

As far as I know, when the user swipe the slide to the next (not using next button on amp-carousel) and rotate the device, that happens. So I think there is a problem with swipe actions but no way how to fix on my side.

This happens on all amp-carousel implements on iphone safari browser.

```
<amp-carousel class="carousel1"
  layout="responsive"
  height="450"
  width="500"
  type="slides">
  <div class="slide">
    <amp-img src="/static/samples/img/Border_Collie.jpg"
      layout="responsive"
      width="500"
      height="300"
      alt="Border Collie"></amp-img>
    <amp-fit-text layout="responsive"
      width="500"
      height="150"> The Border Collie is a working and herding dog breed developed in the Anglo-Scottish border region for herding livestock, especially sheep. It was specifically bred for intelligence and obedience. Considered highly intelligent, and typically extremely energetic, acrobatic, smart and athletic, they frequently compete with great success in dog sports, in addition to their success in sheepdog trials. They are often cited as the most intelligent of all domestic dogs. Border Collies also remain employed throughout the world in their traditional work of herding livestock. </amp-fit-text>
  </div>

  <div class="slide">
    <amp-img src="/static/samples/img/Shetland_Sheepdog.jpg"
      layout="responsive"
      width="500"
      height="340"
      alt="Shetland Sheepdog"></amp-img>
    <amp-fit-text layout="responsive"
      width="500"
      height="110"> The Shetland Sheepdog, often known as the Sheltie, is a breed of herding dog. Less favored nicknames are the Toy Collie and the Miniature Collie. They are small dogs, and come in a variety of colors, such as sable, tri-color, and blue merle. They are very intelligent, vocal, excitable, energetic dogs who are always willing to please and work hard.
    </amp-fit-text>
  </div>

  <div class="slide">
    <amp-img src="/static/samples/img/Hovawart.jpg"
      layout="responsive"
      width="500"
      height="350"
      alt="Hovawart"></amp-img>
    <amp-fit-text layout="responsive"
      width="500"
      height="100">
      The Hovawart is a medium to large size German dog breed. The name of the breed means "an estate
      guard dog", which is the original use for the breed. The breed originated in the Black Forest
      region and was first described in text and paintings in medieval times.
    </amp-fit-text>
  </div>
</amp-carousel>
```

Comment: what happens when you switch back to v0.1? i just checked a carousel on safari (portrait, landscape) using 0.1 and 0.2 - both work basically the same (0.2 has a smooth scroll)

Comment: on version 0.1, it is same.

Comment: try using conventional HTML instead of `amp-fit-text`. our versions, sans `amp-fit-text`, work as expected. and - just in case - escape the text double quotes; should not be necessary, but ...